# Use a global variable as param for an action-bound method

Tags: javascript, jsf-2

As I'm not a javascript nor a jsf expert, I ask if it is possible to define a global variable and then pass it as a parameter for an action-bound method.
Maybe it is more clear with an example... :)

In my xhtml code should be something like this:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  var isEdit = "false";

  //<![CDATA[ 
    function editSelected(selBox, inputFiled)
    {
      var htmlstring = selBox.options[selBox.selectedIndex].text;
      inputFiled.value = htmlstring;
      isEdit = "true";
    }
  //]]>
</script>

...

<h:commandLink
  styleClass="waiButton"
  value="#{lakshmiMsg.commonButtonAdd}"
  action="#{detailController.addCreator(**isEdit**)}"
  rendered="#{detailModel.mode != detailModel.viewMode}">
</h:commandLink>
...
```

Would be something like this possible?
If not, are there maybe other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alter a hidden input field by JS. E.g.

```
<h:inputHidden id="edit" value="#{bean.edit}" />
```

with

```
document.getElementById("form:edit").value = isEdit;
```

An alternative is to just don't do the `editSelected()` job in JS, but instead do the job in pure JSF with `<f:ajax>` magic. As the functional requirements for this are not clear because the code is incomplete and not self-documenting enough, I can't give a kickoff example for that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is probably better handled by letting your JavaScript update a hidden form field.  The action on the commandLink is evaluated on the server, while the function in JavaScript runs in the browser.

With a hidden form field, you can check it in your addCreator method (not as a param, but from the request) to see if you are in edit mode.